# Hello Friend Spec from Test First Live Ruby Issue

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to do a spec from test first, the link is this: http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/hello_friend. The instructions say I will see the uninitialized Constant Friend (NameError) when I type in rake in the ruby command prompt and this is exactly what I saw. So I follow the instructions further and opened up *friend.rb* and created the empty class:

```
class Friend
end
```

Now the instructions tell me to save it and run the test again. But I am still receiving the

```
 uninitilized Constant Friend (NameError)
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `require` and/or `require_relative` at the top of `friend_spec.rb` to require the file that defines the `Friend` class.  That tutorial doesn't seem to tell you about this, unforunately.  Without seeing your entire directory structure and your code, I can't give a more specific answer.

**EDIT:** Are you running this code on your computer or are you running it at http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/hello_friend ?  Maybe my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: i'm running it on my computer from C:\Users\Mycomputer\desktop\learn_ruby\07_hello_friend

Comment: Without seeing your entire directory structure and your code, I can't give a more specific answer.  You didn't tell me the names of any Ruby files.